# SQL Server query and duplicates

Tags: sql, sql-server, duplicates

Disclaimer - My knowledge of SQL Server is limited. So I apologize in advance if this is a 'dumb' question.

Purpose of query - gathering information from a multi-table database from a program our company uses and depositing the results into our web database so we can display some of the information.

Issue - duplicate information. Part of the issue is that there are multiple instances of people in the database, so there are results duplicated that way... and the other duplicates come from the join. I need to combine the results so that I deposit just one result with the same Name or Code (ID). The rest of the information I would like to combine so that I don't lose any information that may be needed.

Here is query I have:

```
SELECT people.Code AS [athlete-id],
    people.Name AS [athlete-name],
    people.DOB AS [DOB],
    people.Division AS [agency-id],
    certifs.[Expiration date] AS [expiration-date], 
    groups.Name AS [agency-name],
    address.Addresses AS [address],
    address.City AS [city],
    address.State AS [state],
    case when tags.Field = 'ABJD86GHKXXQWA9Q'
        then tags.Value 
    end AS [restrictions], 
    case when tags.Field = 'VH2C78N9A15S059T'
        then tags.Value 
    end AS [comments]
FROM people 
LEFT OUTER JOIN certifs 
    ON people.Code = certifs.Owner 
LEFT OUTER JOIN groups 
    ON people.Division = groups.Code 
LEFT OUTER JOIN address 
    ON people.Code = address.Owner 
LEFT OUTER JOIN tags 
    ON people.Code = tags.Owner 
ORDER BY [agency-name], [athlete-name]
```

Let me know of any questions you may have. I appreciate the help.

Comment: Why are you depositing this into a seperate database?  You should be able to just query the SQL Server database itself... Also, you appear to be expecting duplicate rows, given the way you're referring to `tags.Field` - add the clause as part of the `JOIN` condition (and use two references to the table, not one).  If you have duplicate people data, that's a problem that should be resolved seperately from this issue.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "multiple instances of people"? Does that mean rows with identical name or code or both? What do you mean by "The rest of the information I would like to combine".

Comment: They need to be deposited into a seperate database because where they exist is not a database that can be accessed from the web.  A cron job runs... opens a firewall window... and then dumps the information into the seperate database.

"multiple instances of people" - Example: Name: Bill Jones ID: 12345... are the same for 20 results returned... however the results will return multiple differing date for the other fields like address (because of address change) or comments because of multiple comments.

Answer (score 0):

How about if you insert DISTINCT right after SELECT and before people.Code ?

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
people.Code [...]
```

Comment: I tried but some of the columns I am selecting are ntext. Which aren't comparable.

Comment: Ok... so I converted the ntext statements to varchar during the select to get rid of the error from using distinct... but I am still getting duplicates.

Comment: you could try "FROM people,certifs,groups,address,tags  WHERE people.Code = certifs.Owner AND people.Division = groups.Code AND people.Code = address.Owner AND people.Code = tags.Owner 
ORDER BY [agency-name], [athlete-name]" and see if your engine can handle it

Comment: @Ameoo - use of the implicit `JOIN` syntax (`FROM ...., ....`) is considered an SQL anti-pattern, and is to be avoided.  Mostly because it can make some of the comparisons mysterious, but also because specifying your join conditions in the `WHERE` clause can actually change your results slightly.  Whenever possible, specify all criteria in the `JOIN` itself.

Comment: I appreciate the help... but I'm still getting duplicate results.  I have tried Group By as well... and I still can't resolve the issue.

Comment: If I could find a way to combine all the results so that there is only one result set per ID and Name... and then the rest of the columns would combine results from all duplicates seperated by a comma, then atleast I could get it all down to one row per athlete... and would be sure not to lost any data as it gets dumped into the web server.

Comment: have you tried starting with no joins and adding each table one at a time to determine which table it is that contains the duplicate data so that then you can determine which record from that table you want information from?

Comment: @X-Zero, I know it's something to avoid and some engines don't support it, but I wanted to see if he gets the results.